# How to prove this? (set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then $|A \cap B| \leqslant {|A|+|B|\over 2}$.

What I already did:

We know that $|A| + |B| = |A \cup B| + |A \cap B|$ and $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$.

So,  $|A| + |B| > {|A \cap B|\over 2}$

${|A|+|B|\over 2} > {|A \cap B|\over 2}$

Proof:

$A \cap B \subseteq A$ $\Rightarrow$ $|A \cap B| \leqslant |A|$

$A \cap B \subseteq A$ $\Rightarrow$ $|A \cap B| \leqslant |B|$

$|B| \ge |A \cap B|$

$|A| \ge |A \cap B|$

$|A| + |B| \ge  |A \cap B| + |A|$

$|B| + |A| \ge  |A \cap B| + |B|$

$ 2(|A| + |B|) \ge 2 |A \cap B| + |B| + |A|$

$|A| + |B| \ge 2 |A \cap B|$

${|A|+|B|\over 2} \ge |A \cap B|$

Comment: $|A| \cap |B|$??!

Comment: sorry. I delete it until I get used to this writing. Or edit it.

Comment: Yes, I also read it, in the end of my book, that I should use this expression. But I dont understand it. Could you use words for it?

Comment: Don't forget to put dollar signs on either side of an expression you want rendered as MathJax.

Comment: I try to use this site. It will take some time. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for the dollar signs!

Comment: The notations are still confusing, even after the edit. What does it mean to add a set with the cardinality of another set, and to "intersect" two cardinalities? That's where I (and probably everyone else) get lost.

Comment: Sorry, I think now it is good. yes it is not $|A| \cap |B|$
but $|A \cap B|$

Comment: I would just need a hint.

Comment: Hint: $A \cap B\subseteq A \implies |A \cap B|\le|A|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $|A\cap B| \leqslant \min \{|A|,|B|\}$.

Note that $|A\cap B| \leqslant |A|$ and $|A\cap B| \leqslant |B|$. Therefore,
$$ |A\cap B|+ |A\cap B| \leqslant \ldots?$$
What can we write instead of $\ldots$ that would prove what we need?

Comment: Thank you for everyone! Now I need some time.

Comment: I am not sure about it, what the last expression means.  I got it, that A intersection B is less, or equal to A, and also to B. What does min{|A|, |B|} mean?

Comment: @Holdviola It's effectively the same hint as the one given by Jaap Scherphuis in the comments. $\min \{a,b\}$ is the smallest number among the two. Do note that $|A|,|B|$ are natural numbers because we assume the sets are finite.

Comment: I think I did it! I am very happy about it. Thank you! I think I would have liked math better if we have had more proofs in school.