# Set theory proof by induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Prove, that if $A_1, A_2,\ldots ,A_k$ are finite sets, then show that $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_k| \leqslant  {(|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|+...|(A_k)|)\over k}$

I already showed this: [How to prove this? (set theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545586/how-to-prove-this-set-theory/4545641#4545641)

And I also showed it, similarly to $k=2$ for $k=3$. I know I have to use the induction method, but I am unfamiliar with proving something generally. So my problem is, how should I notate this generally.

Comment: Make your induction hypothesis for the case $n$ and try to deduce the case $n+1$ from it.

Comment: The argument I gave in my answer is exactly the same for the general case. Induction is unnecessary. If it holds that $b\leqslant a_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots, n$, then it holds that $nb \leqslant a_1+\ldots + a_n$.